# How to vi editor append special character?

Tags: vi

Please  suggest how to append underscore at the end of each string which it start with ^test only

testboxes01
testboxes02

I am trying to get

testboxes01_
testboxes02_

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on my machine and with my test cases:

[image]

Oops, omit that first `\s`.
That says:

> g - globally, throughout the file
>
> /^test/ - on lines starting with "test"
>
> s - substitute
>
> the word "test" and any trailing letters, captured as group 1 (by the escaped parentheses)
>
> /\1 - for capture group 1 from above
>
> _  - followed by an underscore

If you do it a lot, you can store it in a file, copy it with your mouse and paste it in easily :-)

Comment: sorry, my typo. somehow its not adding _ at the end of the string . I am trying with :g/^test/s^\(test\w*\)/\1_       Thank you